# Efficient NumPy way of rolling nanstd

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 1-D NumPy array where I create a rolling window and then compute the `np.nanstd`:

```
import numpy as np

def rolling_window(a, window):
    a = np.asarray(a)
    shape = a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1] - window + 1, window)
    strides = a.strides + (a.strides[-1],)

    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = 100_000_000
    nan_indices = np.random.choice(np.arange(n), size=1000, replace=False)
    T = np.random.rand(n)
    T[nan_indices] = np.nan
    m = 50
    np.nanstd(rolling_window(T, m), axis=T.ndim)
```

However, I noticed that not only is this extremely time consuming, it also uses a lot of memory. Is there a way to improve both the memory and speed performance (Numba is an option)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### NumPy vectorized

After grueling through the math, here's what I ended up with few `np.convolve` and some masking to get a vectorized NumPy solution -

```
def nanstd(a, W):
    k = np.ones(W, dtype=int)
    m = ~np.isnan(a)
    a0 = np.where(m, a,0)
    
    n = np.convolve(m,k,'valid')
    c1 = np.convolve(a0, k,'valid')
    f2 = c1**2
    p2 = f2/n**2
    f1 = np.convolve((a0**2)*m,k,'valid')+n*p2
    out = np.sqrt((f1 - (2/n)*f2)/n)
    return out
```

- Complete Explanation is at the end of this post.

#### Pandas equivalent

Here's the equivalent pandas version, which isn't too bad on performance -

```
import pandas as pd

def pdroll(T,m):
    return pd.Series(T).rolling(m).std(ddof=0).values[m-1:]
```

#### Benchmarking

Using [`benchit`](https://github.com/droyed/benchit) package (few benchmarking tools packaged together; disclaimer: I am its author) to benchmark proposed solutions.

```
def setup(n):
    nan_indices = np.random.choice(np.arange(n), size=10, replace=False)
    T = np.random.rand(n)
    T[nan_indices] = np.nan
    return T

import benchit
f = {'rolling': lambda T,m: np.nanstd(rolling_window(T, m), axis=T.ndim),
     'pdroll': pdroll, 'conv':nanstd}
in_={(n,w):(setup(n),w) for n in 10**np.arange(2,6) for w in [5,10,20,50,80,100]}
t = benchit.timings(f, in_, multivar=True)
t.plot(logx=True, sp_ncols=2, save='timings.png', dpi=200)
```

[image]

NumPy one is good on smaller window sizes, while pandas is better on larger ones.

---

**NumPy vectorized : Explanation on NumPy version `nanstd`**

Basically, `np.nanstd` is computing `std` ignoring `NaNs`. Now, `std` can be computed based on `mean`.

Thus, for an array `a` with no `NaNs`, it would be :

```
np.sqrt(np.mean((a-np.mean(a))**2))   # (1)
```

Let's prove it :

```
In [43]: a = np.arange(1,6).astype(float)

In [44]: np.nanstd(a)
Out[44]: 1.4142135623730951

In [45]: np.sqrt(np.mean((a-np.mean(a))**2))
Out[45]: 1.4142135623730951
```

Now, let's say, we have a `NaN` in it :

```
In [46]: a[2] = np.nan

In [47]: a
Out[47]: array([ 1.,  2., nan,  4.,  5.])
```

The `std` with `nanstd` would be :

```
In [48]: np.nanstd(a)
Out[48]: 1.5811388300841898
```

Let's figure out the equivalent one based on `(1)`.

Let's start with `(a-np.mean(a))**2`.

This one : ?

```
In [72]: (a-np.mean(a))**2
Out[72]: array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan])
```

No!

This one : ?

```
In [73]: (a0 - np.sum(a0)/n)**2
Out[73]: array([4., 1., 9., 1., 4.])
```

No! Because `a` is :

```
In [76]: a
Out[76]: array([ 1.,  2., nan,  4.,  5.])
```

We need to make the `NaN` position one `0`.

This one : ?

```
In [75]: m*((a0 - np.sum(a0)/n)**2)
Out[75]: array([4., 1., 0., 1., 4.])
```

Yes!

Then, what's `np.mean((a-np.mean(a))**2)`? It would be, sum of those in `[75]` divided by `n` :

```
In [77]: np.sum(m*((a0-np.sum(a0)/n)**2))/n
Out[77]: 2.5
```

Hence, the final std value :

```
In [78]: np.sqrt(np.sum(m*((a0-np.sum(a0)/n)**2))/n)
Out[78]: 1.5811388300841898
```

Summarizing :

```
In [55]: m = ~np.isnan(a)       # (2)
    ...: a0 = np.where(m, a,0)
    ...: n = m.sum()
    ...: out0 = np.sqrt(np.sum(m*((a0-np.sum(a0)/n)**2))/n)

In [56]: out0
Out[56]: 1.5811388300841898
```

Next part is incorporating the sliding nature. So, we need to do `(2)` in a sliding nature. So, the first two steps remains.

Hence, it starts off with :

```
m = ~np.isnan(a)
a0 = np.where(m, a,0)
```

But the last two would change, let's see how.

Let's focus on the final step to compute `out0`. We have :

```
m*((a0-np.sum(a0)/n)**2)
```

Then, we compute the summation :

```
np.sum(m*((a0-np.sum(a0)/n)**2))
```

We have : `(a-b)**2 = a**2 + b**2 - 2*a*b`. So, earlier step becomes

```
np.sum(m*(a0**2 + (np.sum(a0)/n)**2 - 2*a0*np.sum(a0)/n))
```

Further re-arranging leads to :

```
np.sum(m*(a0**2 + (np.sum(a0)/n)**2) - np.sum(2*a0*np.sum(a0)/n))

np.sum(m*(a0**2 + (np.sum(a0)/n)**2)) - np.sum(2*a0*np.sum(a0)/n)

np.sum(m*(a0**2 + (np.sum(a0)/n)**2)) - 2*np.sum(a0*np.sum(a0))/n

np.sum(m*(a0**2 + (np.sum(a0)/n)**2)) - (2/n)*np.sum(a0*np.sum(a0)) # (3)
```

Let's focus on the first two parts for the summation.

Also, let's take a sample case to make things concrete. We will setup two datasets - One for the complete array setup and another a windowed version of the complete one.

Setup :

```
#=========================== 1. Complete setup
a = np.arange(1,10).astype(float)
a[[2,5]] = np.nan

W = 5
k = np.ones(W, dtype=int)
m_comp = ~np.isnan(a)
a0_comp = np.where(m_comp, a,0)

n_comp = np.convolve(m_comp,k,'valid')
c1 = np.convolve(a0_comp, k,'valid')
c2 = np.convolve((a0_comp**2)*m_comp,k,'valid')

#=========================== 2. Windowed setup
a1 = np.arange(1,6).astype(float)
a1[2] = np.nan
m = ~np.isnan(a1)
a0 = np.where(m, a1,0)
n = m.sum()
out0 = np.sqrt(np.sum(m*((a0-np.sum(a0)/n)**2))/n)
```

From windowed setup, we have :

```
In [51]: np.sum(m*(a0**2 + (np.sum(a0)/n)**2))
Out[51]: 82.0

In [52]: np.sum(m*(a0**2) + m*((np.sum(a0)/n)**2))
Out[52]: 82.0

In [53]: np.sum(m*(a0**2)) + np.sum(m*((np.sum(a0)/n)**2))
Out[53]: 82.0
```

First summation part :

```
In [86]: np.sum(m*(a0**2))
Out[86]: 46.0

# complete setup version :
In [87]: c2
Out[87]: array([ 46.,  45.,  90., 154., 219.])
```

Second summation part :

```
In [54]: np.sum(m*((np.sum(a0)/n)**2))
Out[54]: 36.0

# complete setup version :
In [55]: n_comp*(c1/n_comp)**2
Out[55]: 
array([ 36.        ,  40.33333333,  85.33333333, 144.        ,
       210.25      ])
```

The remaining piece of puzzle fromn `(3)` is :

```
In [79]: (2/n)*np.sum(a0*np.sum(a0))
Out[79]: 72.0
```

Let's focus on the meat of it :

```
In [80]: np.sum(a0*np.sum(a0))
Out[80]: 144.0
```

On the complete setup, it would correspond to :

```
In [81]: c1**2
Out[81]: array([144., 121., 256., 576., 841.])
```

Thus, for the entire remaining piece :

```
In [82]: (2/n)*np.sum(a0*np.sum(a0))
Out[82]: 72.0

# complete setup version :
In [83]: (2/n_comp)*c1**2
Out[83]: 
array([ 72.        ,  80.66666667, 170.66666667, 288.        ,
       420.5       ])
```

Hence, `(3)` and its complete version counterpart would be :

```
In [89]: np.sum(m*(a0**2 + (np.sum(a0)/n)**2)) - (2/n)*np.sum(a0*np.sum(a0))
Out[89]: 10.0

In [90]: c2 + n_comp*(c1/n_comp)**2 - (2/n_comp)*c1**2
Out[90]: array([10.        ,  4.66666667,  4.66666667, 10.        ,  8.75      ])
```

To get the final std values, we need to divide by the count of valid ones per window and then apply `sqrt` :

```
In [99]: np.sqrt((c2 + n_comp*(c1/n_comp)**2 - (2/n_comp)*c1**2)/n_comp)
Out[99]: array([1.58113883, 1.24721913, 1.24721913, 1.58113883, 1.47901995])
```

Hence, with some cleanup, we end up with the final `nanstd` version.

Comment: I would like to accept this answer as it is indeed faster and my memory efficient than `np.nanstd`. Any chance you are able to point to some references for your convolve solution? Anything explaining how the steps relate to computing `std` would be helpful for long term maintenance as I would like to document it. Would something like Welford’d approach possibly be faster?

Comment: Additionally, is there a way to generalize this so that it also works for a 2D array as input?

Comment: Also, is this equation susceptible to catastrophic cancellation when the variance is small compared to the mean?

Comment: @slaw Added explanations. 1) No idea about Welford’d approach . 2) 2D - Please post a new question. 3) Catastrophic cancellation : Not sure about that.